# Как отследить добавления класа и реагировать на него?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть скрипт который **добавляет / отнимает** класс `"is-active"` к елементу с классом `".c-hamburger"`  **нужно  переделать/написать** скрипт чтоб он отслеживал это **добавление/отнимания** класа и **добавлял / отнимал**  клас к другому елементу (по ID напиример ) на станице

вот скрипт

```
(function() {     

      "use strict";

      var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

      for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var toggle = toggles[i];
        toggleHandler(toggle);
      };

      function toggleHandler(toggle) {
        toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
        });
      }

    })();
```

Comment: Немного странный подход. Вы же наверняка знаете в следствии чего хотите добавить класс(например по нажатию на элемент)? А раз знаете причину добавления, значит можете отследить наличие добавляемого класса у других элементов.

Comment: Может быть стоит попробовать Vuejs? Тогда "все будет связано". Второй вариант - в процедуре добавление класса создавать событие, которое будет отловлено, и добавит к другому элементу класс.

Comment: Я тоже за то, что изменение класса второго элемента лучше повесить на событие, меняющее класс первого элемента, но на всякий случай -  с помощью MutationObserver() можно отслеживать любые изменения HTML-кода.

Answer (score 1):

Можно триггерить `change` после `toggle` и его потом обрабатывать.

```js
$('.c-hamburger').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active').trigger('change');
});
$('.c-hamburger').on('change', function() {
  $('#foo').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.is-active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='c-hamburger'>
Hamburger1
</button>
<button class='c-hamburger'>
Hamburger2
</button>
<div id='foo'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

А можно еще как-то так:

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector('.add');
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const removeButton = document.querySelector('.remove');

const source = document.querySelector('.source');
const destination = document.querySelector('.destination');

/* Хэндл для Proxy */
const handle = {
  /* будем слушать вызов метода */
  apply(target,thisArg,argList){
    /* Сначала выполним вызов, который требуется по запросу */
    const result = Reflect.apply(target,thisArg,argList);
    /* Потом выполним метод с такими же именем, контекстом и 
        параметрами для destination.classList  */
    Reflect.apply(destination.classList[target.name],
                  destination.classList,
                  argList);
    return result;
  }
};

/* Создадим прокси на каждую процедуру classList */
['add', 'toggle', 'remove', 'replace'].map(method=>{
   const proxy = new Proxy(source.classList[method], handle);
   Object.defineProperty(source.classList, method, {get(){return proxy;}});
});

/* ВСЁ! Дальше мы можем делать что угодно с классами source.
   После каждого вызова метода source.classList будет вызван 
    аналогочный метод destination.classList. */

/* Обратите внимание, клики по кнопкам меняют класс только у source */
addButton.addEventListener('click',()=>source.classList.add('is-active'));
toggleButton.addEventListener('click',()=>source.classList.toggle('is-active'));
removeButton.addEventListener('click',()=>source.classList.remove('is-active'));
```

```css
.source, .destination { width: 100px; background-color: #888; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; display: inline-block; }
.source.is-active, .destination.is-active { color: #fff; background-color: #f00; }
```

```html
<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<button class="remove">Remove</button>

<div class='source'>source</div>

<div class='destination'>destination</div>
```

Не то, что бы в этом коде открыл Америку, но способ гибкий, универсальный. Если приложить к идее голову, то можно довести до идеала.